# Can an apartment complex force place insurance on a renter's account?

Tags: civil-law, colorado

Some apartment complexes require renter's insurance in accordance with their lease terms, but can the apartment complex force insurance on the renter's account?

Comment: What do you mean - force on the account? Do mean can the manager buy insurance and add the cost to the lease?